# Create jasmine spy on chained promise

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I would like to test a service that is based on Restangular. The issue is that I don't find a way to create the correct spy on chained promise.

```
var services = angular.module('services.dashboards', ['models.dashboards', 'models.metrics', 'LocalStorageModule', 'app.filters']);

services.factory('DashboardsService', ['Restangular', '$q', 'Metrics', 'Dashboards', 'localStorageService', '$filter', 'filterByGradedFilter', function (Restangular, $q, Metrics, Dashboards, localStorageService, $filter, filterByGradedFilter) {
    var factory = {};

    factory.getData = function () {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        var data = localStorageService.get('data');
        if (!data) {
            Dashboards.post()
                .then(function (result) {
                    return Restangular.oneUrl('newDash', result.data).get();
                })
                .then(function (result) {
                    data = result.data;
                    localStorageService.set('data', data);
                    defer.resolve(data);
                });
        } else {
            defer.resolve(data);
        }
        return defer.promise;
    }

    return factory;

}]);
```

The chained promise I want to test is:

```
            Dashboards.post()
                .then(function (result) {
                    return Restangular.oneUrl('newDash', result.data).get();
                })
                .then(function (result) {
                    data = result.data;
                    localStorageService.set('data', data);
                    defer.resolve(data);
                });
```

The test is running but I get an error: `Error: get() method does not exist`:

```
describe('Dashboards Service', function () {

    // Holds the service under test
    var service;
    // Dependencies
    var dashboards;
    var restangular;
    var q;
    var rootScope;

    beforeEach(module('services.dashboards'));

    // We inject the service
    beforeEach(inject(function (_DashboardsService_, _Dashboards_, _Restangular_, _$q_, _$rootScope_) {
        service = _DashboardsService_;
        dashboards = _Dashboards_;
        restangular = _Restangular_;
        q = _$q_;
        rootScope = _$rootScope_
    }));

    describe('#getData', function ($rootScope) {
        it('should get a dashboard', function () {
            spyOn(dashboards, 'post').and.returnValue(q.when({}));
            // Tried that but it's not working
            spyOn(restangular, 'oneUrl').and.callFake(function() {
                return this;
                // Also tried return restangular;
            });
            spyOn(restangular, 'get').and.returnValue(q.when({}));
            service.getData().then(function (result) {
                expect(result).toEqual({});
            });

            expect(dashboards.post).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(restangular.oneUrl).toHaveBeenCalledWith('newDash');
            expect(restangular.oneUrl.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
            rootScope.$apply();

        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try this

```
 spyOn(restangular, 'oneUrl').and.callFake(function() {
               return {
                    get:function() {return q.when({});}
               }
            });
```

Basically you need to return object that has get method that returns a promise or data.